# firebase pubsub function cron job with range of start and end time

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions

I want to fetch data *daily every minute from 10am until 4am the next morning*.
Is this possible in one pubsub function with firebase functions?

```
exports.getFeed = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun(context => {
// get my feed every minute, but how to specify a daily range?
}
```

For a cron job to start and stop you'd usually need two lines I believe, but how to do that here?
Or do I need two pubsub functions?

Answer (score 1):

[Cron syntax](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) has a way to specify ranges for the time components, which looks like this in your case, using the hours component:

```
* 10-23,0-4 * * *
```

10-23 indicates 10am to 11pm, and 0-4 continues from midnight to 4am.

Comment: thanks, so this will also keep running between 11:00pm and 00:00am every minute? How about * * 10-4 * * ?

Comment: And looking at the syntax, I believe hours come in second place, so then it would be 
* 10-4 * * *

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests that the second number in a range can be less than the first number.  But you're free to try it.

Comment: I've been trying jobs with a syntax like * 6-7 * * * but the pubsub function doesn't stop running at the 'end hour', in this example 7am.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.  It sounds like you just need to adjust the hour range.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, just tried to say that, no matter what end hour after the hyphen, the job didn't stop, so my question was still the same. Now I understand that the end hour is included, not excluded. So * 6-7 * * * works for a job from 6 to 8 am. I didn't test your answer. To prevent further confusion about earlier comments, maybe it'd be good to note that your answer has been edited in the meantime? Thanks for the help!